# Robot framework - get a value from a list

Tags: robotframework, rpa

I have used the `Get Column Values` from `ExcelLibrary` in order to get an entire column from a particular excel file, the column was assined to `@{vinrange}` as `[ ('A1', u'VIN') | ('A2', u'032145') | ('A3', u'051478') | ('A4', u'124578') ]`

I want to do a loop in order to only get the value (2nd argument) as `[ 'VIN' , '032145' , '051478' , '124578' ]`

[image]

How can i accomplish that? I'm using Ride

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of the `LOG    ${VAR1}` for the first element is,
`('A1', u'VIN')` then it is a tuple. You can use it like a list, so to get the second tuple member, you can use:
`LOG    ${VAR1[1]}`